# Schema.org microdata type for computer and service daemon?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

With the schema.org microdata vocabulary, what type of object is most appropriate for representing an instance of a computer (like a web server) and an instance of a daemon (ex. httpd, mysql, etc)?

What I came up with is, a non-instance of a computer might be a [Product](http://schema.org/Product) (ex. Dell PowerEdge 1950), a specific instance an [IndividualProduct](http://schema.org/IndividualProduct), the OS [Code](http://schema.org/Code), the OS instance [Intangible](http://schema.org/Intangible).

A daemon would be [Code](http://schema.org/Code) and an instance an [Intangible](http://schema.org/Intangible).

In the case of the computer and software instances as IndividualProduct and Intangible respectively, it seems like the thing to do would be to [extend those base types](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) to add relevant properties.

I'm hoping someone with more experience can weigh in and give feedback on how close to the mark I am here, and provide corrections where appropriate as well as more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About schema.org/Product and Servers**

As unor wrote, Product (and IndividualProduct) type is more suitable for something that is made  for sale. It is intended for use along with schema.org/Offer or at manufacturer site who sales products through retailers. Moreover about a year ago it was extended with GoodRelations which is huge ontology exactly for e-commerce ([post](http://blog.schema.org/2012/11/good-relations-and-schemaorg.html) about integration at schema blog, GoodRelations [details](http://purl.org/goodrelations/)).

As, I guess, you don't sell servers you need smth like schema.org/Computer type with child schema.org/Server which are not there unfortunately. So this is what I suggest - to propose appropriate types to schema.org working group (more about this below). Besides I'm not sure that you need separate type for particular instance. Instead consider including *instance* property to your *Computer* type. Structure will be like

```
Computer
  properties about configuration
  instance -> instance1
  instance -> instance2
...
```

One more option is to define *ComputerConfiguration* type. And every instance will be *Computer* which refers (with spec property) to *ComputerConfiguration* via microdata *itemref*.

Maybe the last one is silly - one need to play with yours and similar cases to find proper structure.

**About Code, Intangible and running apps**

*Code* type was proposed with source code in mind, not running application. You can find out more at schema [blog post](http://blog.schema.org/2012/06/newvocabularies-for-technical.html) where several types (and Code) were introduced.

> These proposed vocabularies will improve search engines’ understanding
>   of documentation with technical content, and thus greatly increase the
>   discoverability of this documentation.
>   ...
>
> Code Defines section of content as sample code
>
> ```
> This Code is a C++ sample inserted in an article:
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code">
>   <meta itemprop="name" content=" Allocating Memory from a NUMA Node "/>
>   <meta itemprop="sampleType" content=" inline"/>
>   <div itemprop="programmingLanguage">
>   C++
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

*Intangible*... Well, personally I don't think you should touch it. Description says

> A utility class that serves as the umbrella for a number of
>   'intangible' things such as quantities, structured values, etc.

In fact this is basket where all types without better place in hierarchy lay. And I don't see at all why you need to use it.

As unor points schema.org/SoftwareApplication seems to be the most appropriate type for you. Keep in mind though that its prototype is Google [Software Application Rich Snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1645432?hl=en). Which is more about, you know, mobile and browser apps (with reviews, price, etc). But if you're OK with properties, I don't think it'll be strong contradiction to use it for describing running daemons.

Again instances can be described via specific property you can extend SoftwareApplication with.

**About new vocabs proposal process**

As Yandex representative in Schema.org I can tell a bit about accepting proposals process. Well, there is no strict process :) Basically if you want your new type (or extensions) to be included in main vocab you should take a few steps:

- describe your proposal (.pdf file is nice). Don't afraid to be too verbose: more details - the clearer use cases. Particular use cases and examples are very much appreciated.
- send it to [public-vocabs](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/) maillist. BTW it is open, you can sign in and discover hot discussions about other proposals.
- Get feedback, correct proposal and iteratively get to the best proposal for everyone.
- ...
- Profit!

And be persistent :)

Light version is just to send this very question to public-vocabs and get some reaction. Maybe community there can advise some vocabularies for you that can be used with schema.org via [rdfa syntax](http://blog.schema.org/2012/06/semtech-rdfa-microdata-and-more.html) or [external enumerations](http://blog.schema.org/2012/05/schemaorg-markup-for-external-lists.html) extension mechanism.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit from 2019-01**: The definition for `Product` was changed later on; while it [could be used now](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/117714/17633) even if the server is/was nowhere offered for sale, I would still suggest to use something else instead, unless there is *some* sale context.)

---

[`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) is defined as "A product is anything that is made available for sale". I don’t think it applies in your case, as you are not referring to the servers as a product for sale. The same goes for [`IndividualProduct`](http://schema.org/IndividualProduct), as it’s just more specific.

[`Code`](http://schema.org/Code) would only be suitable if you are referring to the actual source code. [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) might be more appropriate.

I’m not sure if Schema.org is capable of differentiating a software from a running instance of that software. Maybe a daemon *might* be an [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) or an [`Action`](http://schema.org/Action) *in addition* to [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I'm considering drafting up some new schemas but wanted to get some feedback from others who have more familiarity before venturing in that direction.